# import asynchronously in typescript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript, angular, import

I need to import an AMD module written in javascript using System.js in a typescript class (Angular 2). I was able to load the library asynchronously using:

```
System.import('export_name').then(function(instance){
    // deal with instance
};
```

But I need to solve this import synchronously instead of async since the object gets requests before the import is solved (for example, if I put it in the constructor).

I would like to do something like:

```
import * as [instanceName] from 'export_name';
```

But it tells me that it is not a module. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried `let instanceName = require('export_name');` ?

Comment: yes it tried to load a file [export_name].js instead of the export in question. As a precision, the export_name is a specific export in a bundle .js file